# Installation fails to download

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, clickonce

Recently I'm experiencing issue in downloading `ClickOnce` installation of an application.
When I enter my credentials and click on log-in, I'm getting below error in a pop-up,
"**Application download did not succeed. Check your network connection, or contact administrator or network service provider**".
When I click on details below message gets opened in notepad:

```
PLATFORM VERSION INFO
Windows                     : 6.0.6002.131072 (Win32NT)
Common Language Runtime     : 4.0.30319.18408
System.Deployment.dll       : 4.0.30319.34244 built by: FX452RTMGDR
clr.dll                     : 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
dfdll.dll                   : 4.0.30319.34244 built by: FX452RTMGDR
dfshim.dll                  : 4.0.41209.0 (Main.041209-0000)

SOURCES
    Deployment url          : "url"

ERROR SUMMARY
    Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
    * Activation of "url" resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
        + Downloading "url" did not succeed.
        + The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
        + The logon attempt failed

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
    No transaction error was detected.

WARNINGS
    There were no warnings during this operation.

OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
    * [11-12-2014 20:04:24] : Activation of "url" has started.

ERROR DETAILS
    Following errors were detected during this operation.
    * [11-12-2014 20:04:25] System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentDownloadException     (Unknown subtype)
        - Downloading "url" did not succeed.
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            ""
        --- Inner Exception ---
        System.Net.WebException
        - The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
        - Source: System
        - Stack trace:
            ""
        --- Inner Exception ---
        System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception
        - The logon attempt failed
        - Source: System
        - Stack trace:
            ""

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
    No transaction information is available.
```

Also, we have another application hosted in the same server which is having same `ClickOnce` installation, which can be downloaded and this application is launched successfully.

Comment: Looks like the server requires authorization - did you change permissions?

Comment: I think [this](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=691085&seqNum=11) article might help you. It's older, but still should fit to your problem.